# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to use `scan4yellow` from `def scan_for_text():` in another function `def home_screen():` and then use the results from `scan4yellow` and prints them on a label, but it keeps saying that it isn't defined in the `home_screen()` function even when its defined in `scan_for_text():` as a global variable

````
    global scan4yellow
    ##reads in the specific docx you want
    document = docx.Document(r'C:/Users/devff/Documents/Prac2.docx')
    ##makes it so it is an element that is actually editable and usable
    rs = document._element.xpath("//w:r")
    ##microsoft words schema so it knows what the xml is like and the parametres
    WPML_URI = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'
    ##bits and pieces to help find the highlighted pieces of text
    ##then leads onto if statements finding out the highlighted texts colour
    tag_rPr = WPML_URI + 'rPr'
    tag_highlight = WPML_URI + 'highlight'
    tag_val = WPML_URI + 'val'
    tag_t = WPML_URI + 't'
    for word in rs:
        for rPr in word.findall(tag_rPr):
            high = rPr.findall(tag_highlight)
            for hi in high:
                if hi.attrib[tag_val] == 'yellow':
                    scan4yellow = (word.find(tag_t).text.encode('utf-8').lower())
                    #return scan4yellow
                    print(scan4yellow)


def home_screen():
    global home_screen
    global scan4yellow
    home_screen = Toplevel(login_screen)
    home_screen.title("Home Page")
    home_screen.geometry("800x600")

    b1 = Button(home_screen, text="Select File", bg="white", command=getfile)
    l1 = Label(home_screen, bg="white", width="20")
    b2 = Button(home_screen, text="Scan File", width=8, bg="white", command=scan_for_text)
    b3 = Button(home_screen, text="Logout", width=8, bg="white", command=logout)
    b4 = Button(home_screen, text="Quit", width=8, bg="white", command=quit)
#    l1 = Label(home_page, textvariable=scan4yellow).grid(row=3, column=1, padx=(10, 0), pady=(10, 0))
#    t1 = Text.insert(END, "1.0", scan4yellow).grid(row=3, column=1, padx=(10, 0), pady=(10, 0))
    l2 = Label(home_screen, text=scan4yellow) #<----- problem is here 'scan4yellow' is not defined
    #print(scan4yellow)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Note that you define value to scan4yellow variable **if, and only if** there is yellowed text in docx. When I've assigned variable in your snippet outside outermost 'for' loop in scan_for_text function, prints value just fine.

Try to debug your code using

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

just before scan4yellow assignment, and then go upwards until it hits. I am pretty sure you have missed some docx tags (or your input file does not contain text in yellow).

Or scan_for_text is not called at all. In this case global variable stays undefined.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

def scan_for_text():
    global scan4yellow
    if True: # change to False to see your error again
        scan4yellow = 'Whatever'

def home_screen():
    # global scan4yellow # you don't even need it declared global again

    print(scan4yellow)

scan_for_text()
home_screen() #prints "Whatever" as long as scan_for_text is called BEFORE home_screen function
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but I tried the `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` throughout both functions and it only did anything after `l2`, and there is definitely yellow highlighted text. Its fine all until I try to put `scan4yellow` into the label then it says its not defined